# Scrapy Running Results

Tags: scrapy

Just getting started with Scrapy, I'm hoping for a nudge in the right direction.

I want to scrape data from here:

https://www.sportstats.ca/display-results.xhtml?raceid=29360

This is what I have so far:

```
import scrapy
import re

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sportstats'
    start_urls = ['https://www.sportstats.ca/display-results.xhtml?raceid=29360']

    def parse(self, response):
        headings = []
        results = []
        tables = response.xpath('//table')
        headings = list(tables[0].xpath('thead/tr/th/span/span/text()').extract())
        rows = tables[0].xpath('tbody/tr[contains(@class, "ui-widget-content ui-datatable")]')
        for row in rows:
            result = []
            tds = row.xpath('td')
            for td in enumerate(tds):
                if headings[td[0]].lower() == 'comp.':
                    content = None
                elif headings[td[0]].lower() == 'view':
                    content = None
                elif headings[td[0]].lower() == 'name':
                    content = td[1].xpath('span/a/text()').extract()[0]
                else:
                    try:
                        content = td[1].xpath('span/text()').extract()[0]
                    except:
                        content = None
                result.append(content)
            results.append(result)
        for result in results:
            print(result)
```

Now I need to move on to the next page, which I can do in a browser by clicking the "right arrow" at the bottom, which I believe is the following li:

```
<li><a id="mainForm:j_idt369" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget fa fa-angle-right" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;mainForm:j_idt369&quot;,p:&quot;mainForm&quot;,u:&quot;mainForm:result_table mainForm:pageNav mainForm:eventAthleteDetailsDialog&quot;,onco:function(xhr,status,args){hideDetails('athlete-popup');showDetails('event-popup');scrollToTopOfElement('mainForm\\:result_table');;}});return false;"></a>
```

How can I get scrapy to follow that?

Comment: Added current progress to main post.

Comment: this is a javascript rendering problem, I would recommend to use firebug if you are using firefox to check the requests involved, or end up using some javascript rendering services like [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) or Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the url in a browser without javascript you  won't be able to move to the next page. As you can see inside the li tag, there is some javascript to be executed in order to get the next page.

Yo get around this, the first option is usually try to identify the request generated by javascript. In your case, it should be easy: just analyze the java script code and replicate it with python in your spider. If you can do that, you can send the same request from scrapy. If you can't do it, the next option is usually to use some package with javascript/browser emulation or someting like that. Something like ScrapyJS or Scrapy + Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to perform a callback.  Generate the url from the xpath from the 'next page' button.  So `url = response.xpath(xpath to next_page_button)` and then when you're finished scraping that page you'll do `yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_next_page)`. Finally you create a new function called  `def parse_next_page(self, response):`.
A final, final note is if it happens to be in Javascript (and you can't scrape it even if you're sure you're using the correct xpath) check out my repo in using splash with scrapy https://github.com/Liamhanninen/Scrape